# Run the same function with two different preconditions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Any ideas how to not DRY this? The idea is to run multiple function two times with two precondition (=sessions). I don't want to write the preconditions(=session var change) for both function (=doSomething and doAnything)

```
class Foo {
        // run doSomething() 2x with different precondition (=Session var)
        function bla() {
            Session::put('year', 2016);
            doSomething('hello');

            Session::put('year', 2015);
            doSomething('hello');
         }


        function yoo() {

          // run doAnything() 2x with different precondition (=Session var)
          Session::put('year', 2016);
          doAnything('world');

          Session::put('year', 2015);
          doAnything('world');
         }
     }
```

It would be great to have something like this:

```
runWithYears(&doAnything('world'));

function runWithYears(func) {
            Session::put('year', 2016);
            // func should be called here
            exec(func)

            Session::put('year', 2015);
            // func should be called here and will return a different result
            exec(func)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me.

Comment: I don't want to write the preconditions(=session var change) for both function (=doSomething and doAnything). I added some pseudocode as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called **Anonymous functions**.

Anonymous function allows you to declare it as a variable, which allows you to pass it to other functions as if it were any other variable.

**Example** - passing an anonymous function as a parameter & executing it

```
$myFunction = function (){
echo "I'm anonymous";
}

function runWithYears(func){
$func(); // Calling the anonymous function
}

runWithYears(myFunction);
```

> *Output:* I'm anonymous

Answer (score 0):

There must be more to your question than this, but as it is, you can run your functions together after setting variables

```
    Session::put('year', 2016);
    doSomething('hello');
    doAnything('world');

    Session::put('year', 2015);
    doSomething('hello');
    doAnything('world');
```

Comment: Yes, but doSomething() and doAnything() are called in different methods of my class. Any ideas how to encapsulate/extract this into a method?

Answer (score 0):

Write your code like:

```
    // run doSomething() and doAnything() 2x with different precondition (=Session var)

    Session::put('year', 2016);
    doSomething('hello');
    doAnything('world');

    Session::put('year', 2015);
    doSomething('hello');
    doAnything('world');
```

Comment: Yes, but doSomething() and doAnything() are called in different methods of my class. Any ideas how to encapsulate/extract this into a method? – fabian 5 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

replacing your calls to `exec` with `call-user-func` should have the indended effect.

Though personally I would much prefer the 2 methods.

code would be

```
runWithYears('doAnything' , 'world');

function runWithYears(func, arg) {
            Session::put('year', 2016);
            // func should be called here
            call_user_func(func, arg);

            Session::put('year', 2015);
            // func should be called here and will return a different result
            call_user_func(func, arg);
}
```

Though it would be much more maintainable and nicer to use if extracted to 2 methods

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ante Gulin for your help.

This is my working proof of concept using a closure.

```
new Sandbox();

class Sandbox {

    private $message;

    function __construct() {
        $this->first_method();
        $this->second_method();
    }

    private function first_method() {
        $test = function() {
            echo($this->message." peter");
        };

        $this->shout($test);

    }

    private function second_method() {
        $test = function() {
            echo($this->message." spiderman");
        };

        $this->shout($test);
    }


    private function shout($func) {
        $this->message = "hello";
        $func();

        $this->message = "cheerio";
        $func();
    }
}
```